# p:ajax rowSelectCheckbox event is not working in column header check box

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When i select the checkbox inside the data table its working fine but when i select the column header check box only visibly the checkbox get selected but value is setting behind. Is we need to bind the value for the column header check box separatly.

```
<div class="ContentSection">
    <p:tab title="Result" 
           id="dataTable_selectionDemoTab">
        <h2>Table RowSelection with Checkbox</h2>
        <p:panel id="checkboxSelectTableContent_xhtml" >
            <div class="TableSection">
                <p:dataTable value="#{dataTableBean.defaultRecord}" 
                             var="car"
                             id="carDemo33" 
                             style="margin-bottom:0"
                             selection="#{dataTableBean.selectedRecords}"
                             rowKey="#{car.productNmr}">
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" 
                            process="carDemo33" 
                            update="carDemo33,:tableform:multiCarDetail"
                            oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show();" >
                    </p:ajax>
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" 
                            oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show();" 
                            update="carDemo33,:tableform:multiCarDetail" >
                    </p:ajax>
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" 
                              style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>

                    <p:column headerText="productNmr" width="172">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.productNmr}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="productName" width="161">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.productName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="address" width="161">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.address}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="leziDate" width="135">
                        <h:outputText value="#{car.leziDate}" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
            </div>
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</div>
<p:dialog id="tablePopup"  
          header="Selected Cars" 
          widgetVar="multiCarDialog" 
          modal="true" 
          showEffect="fade" 
          hideEffect="fade" 
          resizable="false" 
          width="200">
    <p:outputPanel id="multiCarDetail" 
                   style="text-align:center;">
        <ui:repeat value="#{dataTableBean.selectedRecords}" 
                   var="car">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.productNmr} - #{car.address}" 
                          style="display:block"/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: You means "Check box has been checked but value in selection="#{dataTableBean.selectedRecords} did not set" right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have p:ajax event="toggleSelect" in case handle checkbox is toggled in header.

```
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" 
        oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" 
        update="checkboxDT,:formc:multiCarDetail" >
</p:ajax>
```

Comment: thanks wittakarn now the value are getting binded and checkbox also get selected but the column header checkbox after clicked , the tick mark is not visible in the column headercheckbox

Comment: What about other checkbox? I means other checkboxs which is not a header checkbox. Is it appear?

Comment: yes that checkbox are displayed and checked but only column header checkbox is not checked after clicking that checkbox

Comment: On rowSelectCheckbox event am calling a listener , in that also am facing the same problem that the listener is calling when I am selelcting the body checkbox but when i select the column header checkbox the listener is not calling . can you help me out.

Answer (score 0):

What Primefaces version that you used? If you use Primefaces 5.0 or higher, you must change `oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show();"` to `oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show();"`

This is my example code.

XHTML

```
<h:form id="formc">
    <p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" 
                 var="car" 
                 value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}" 
                 selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" 
                 rowKey="#{car.id}" 
                 style="margin-bottom:0">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" 
                process="checkboxDT" 
                update="checkboxDT,:formc:multiCarDetail"
                oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" >
        </p:ajax>
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" 
                oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" 
                update="checkboxDT,:formc:multiCarDetail" >
        </p:ajax>
        <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" 
                oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" 
                update="checkboxDT,:formc:multiCarDetail" >
        </p:ajax>

        <f:facet name="header">
            Checkbox
        </f:facet>
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" 
                  style="width:2%;text-align:center"/>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Brand">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton process="checkboxDT" 
                             update=":formc:multiCarDetail" 
                             icon="ui-icon-search" 
                             value="View" 
                             oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog header="Selected Cars" 
              widgetVar="multiCarDialog" 
              modal="true" 
              showEffect="fade" 
              hideEffect="fade" 
              resizable="false" 
              width="200">
        <p:outputPanel id="multiCarDetail" 
                       style="text-align:center;">
            <ui:repeat value="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" 
                       var="car">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id} - #{car.brand}" 
                              style="display:block"/>
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="dtSelectionView")
@ViewScoped
public class SelectionView implements Serializable {

    private List<Car> cars6;
    private List<Car> selectedCars;

    @ManagedProperty("#{carService}")
    private CarService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cars6 = service.createCars(10);
    }

    public List<Car> getCars6() {
        return cars6;
    }

    public void setService(CarService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public List<Car> getSelectedCars() {
        return selectedCars;
    }

    public void setSelectedCars(List<Car> selectedCars) {
        this.selectedCars = selectedCars;
    }
}
```

Comment: the sample code which you attached ,in that am not able to get the check box itself

Comment: If you use selectionMode="multiple", p:dataTable will generate checkbox automatically.

Comment: sorry am not getting the checkbox . i have customize the datatable in that datatable the check box is coming but when i checked the column header checkbox the value not get binded